# SharePoint Web Application / IIS Issue

Tags: iis, administration

I created a SharePoint web application on my vm193 virtual machine. I chose the 7777 port number and named the application Sharepoint AppDev Training. Under the URL, I used `http://appdev`. I created a root site collection. I can access the site using `http://vm193:7777`, however I can't access using `http://appdev`.

How can I point `http://appdev` to `http://vm193:7777`?
Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot unless you are using some sort of proxy server such as ISA in between.

`http://appdev` means port 80, while your site is running on port 7777.

You can however, create a Url such as `http://appdev:7777` to access your site by defining host header.